# How to change a variable some time after the function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame

Am trying to block mouse at some time after button click, so I have created a function:

```
import pygame
import game_cache
import time

def set_mouse_blocked(boolean, timer=False):
    if boolean:
        game_cache.is_mouse_active = False

        if timer:
            ...

    else:
        game_cache.is_mouse_active = True
```

How to complete this function without a cycle?

P.S. There is no opportunity to use cycle, because this function called in cycle

Comment: I used pygame module in main script - this file is just a part of all project. timer argument is time of blocking in seconds

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have a main loop function you can create a timestamp with the moment the mouse was blocked and check how far in the past that timestamp is:

```
import time

def init():
    game_cache.is_mouse_active = True
    game_cache.last_blocked = 0
    game_cache.mouse_block_timer = 0

def set_mouse_blocked(timeout = 0):
    game_cache.is_mouse_active = False
    game_cache.last_blocked = time.time()
    game_cache.mouse_block_timer = timeout

def main_loop():
    if game_cache.mouse_block_timer:
        if time.time() - game_cache.last_blocked > game_cache.mouse_block_timer:
            game_cache.is_mouse_active = True
            game_cache.mouse_block_timer = 0
```